# Can equals() and hashCode() be lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, equals, hashcode, class-method

I am new to Java. Can someone explain to me what is the difference between using lambda and method here?

Method equals()

```java
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {

    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Book)) {
      return false;
    }

    Book book = (Book) o;

    if (!author.equals(book.author)) {
      return false;
    }
    return title.equals(book.title);
  }
```

Lambda equals()

```java
  public Function<Object, Boolean> equals = (Object o) -> {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (!(o instanceof Book)) {
      return false;
    }

    Book book = (Book) o;

    if (!author.equals(book.author)) {
      return false;
    }
    return title.equals(book.title);
  };
```

Method hashCode()

```java
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return 31 * author.hashCode() + title.hashCode();
  }
```

Lamba hashCode()

```java
  public Supplier<Integer> hashCode = () -> 31 * author.hashCode() + title.hashCode();
```

I wanted to use Lambda instead of method for equals and hashCode.

Is it OK?

Comment: Method is method, lambda is *instance* representing some functional interface like in your case `Supplier`. Those are entirely different things.

Answer (score 6):

No, it is not OK. Java defines the methods [`boolean equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) and [`int hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode()). This is a specific signature and your suggested solution doesn't meet that signature and doesn't override the default implementation from `Object` (in fact, they are not even methods).

You could *use* a lambda in your `equals` and `hashCode`, but that would just add a needless level of indirection, and make your code harder to read.